# Дополнительная проверка при авторизации

Tags: wordpress

Хочу добавить в форму **авторизации** на вордпресс дополнительное поле. Что то типо капчи.

В форме **РЕГИСТРАЦИИ** делаю так, и все прекрасно работает.

```
add_filter('registration_errors', function ($errors){

// моя проверка (некое дополнительное поле)
if (...) {

    // добавляем ошибку, регистрация останавливается "автоматически"
    $errors->add('error', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: регистрация не удалась');
}

return $errors;

});
```

Я не могу сделать тоже самое на форме авторизации!
Использовал хуки login_errors, wp_login_errors

Answer (score 0):

Для формы авторизации нужно использовать хук **wp_authenticate_user**

```
add_action('wp_authenticate_user', function($user, $password){

    // своя проверка
    if (...) {
        return new WP_Error('error', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: ошибка авторизации');
    }

    return $user;

}, 10, 2 );
```